# XOR or NOT for negation of a variable

Tags: language-agnostic, logical-operators

I was wandering what is better/preferred practice while performing negation of a boolean variable, XOR or NOT?

```
bool someVariable;
```

I even don't know why, but I always use XOR, I just like it more:

```
someVariable ^= true;
```

However, the more obvious way is to use NOT:

```
someVariable = !someVariable;
```

I am probably using the first way so I don't need to type the name of a variable twice, reducing possibility of some errors, typos, etc. It is also less characters to type if the variable is longer than a few chars :)

However, the first way is not really obvious on the first look for anybody who do not use this trick.

Also, the XOR is IMHO more readable because you are sure that the negation is applied on the variable. The NOT could be with two different variables and it is easy to miss if the names look similar:

```
affect = !effect;
```

What are advantages and disadvantages of those two approaches? What should I use? Or it is only matter of personal preference?

Comment: I think both are pretty self-explanatory... Use whatever you want! But it also depends on whom you're coding with. Student => NOT, experienced programmers => your choice. **Just be consistent**.

Comment: Reserve bitwise operations (like xor) for bitwise manipulation. Use `!` to invert a logical value (boolean).  Just don't use use the `!=` compound assignment operator :D

Comment: If you're going to justify the 'only specify the name once' benefit of xor, then you should be flipping a flag such as `library->branch[i]->floor[j]->room[k]->case[l]->shelf[m]->onloan ^= true;`.  Of course, then the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) kicks in anyway.

Comment: if that is the worry, I guess every reasonable language would allow for a function doing something like `negate(affect)` (passing by ref); C++ would, C would force the use of `&` (or macros...), in other OO language there could be a method of the class, e.g. `affect.negate()`, and so on... and IMO if this is the worry, it means variables are poorly named: `affect` can be mistyped/misread as `effect` and viceversa everywhere else in the code, not only when you have to repeat it for a `!`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Semantics

Always go for semantically reasonable code. `someVariable ^= true;` is correct for sure, but might require thinking what it does (and why) to readers *unused* to this version of negating.

`someVariable = !someVariable;` is very explicit about what it is doing: it negates `someVariable` without any possibility nor requirement to interpret it.

#### Further Effects

Furthermore it *might* be that some code analysis software can do whatever it might be able to (optimization, error analysis, ...) with the `!`-version, but fail at the rather unexpected `^`-statement. During compilation, it *might* happen that the XOR-version is slower as (depending on the platform) can require to load `true` into another register before performing the operation. This effect is negligible in probably all cases, but the additional register used might be not.

Comment: If you really need some short hand version, just do something like `function not($value) { !$value }`. Some languages will even allow you to add new operators, you could probably do something like using `!!` for `not(...)`. Anyway, just negating a variable is rather rare (though it does happen, of course); for complex examples like the one @Jonathan Leffler provided you probably should do some more object orientation style without directly providing inner fields anyway.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you should use the NOT approach because its way more readable and one can instantly understand whats going on.

> I am probably using the first way so I don't need to type the name of a variable twice, reducing possibility of some errors, typos, etc. It is also less characters to type if the variable is longer than a few chars :)

If you are using an IDE, you wont be typing more than a couple of chars either way :)

> However, the first way is not really obvious on the first look for anybody who do not use this trick.

Absolutely true. I've never seen this before.

> What should I use? Or it is only matter of personal preference?

Well, code is written once, but read many times, so you should go with the option that most people find more readable, and IMHO, its the "NOT" approach. Reserve the bitwise operators for bitwise operations:)

Answer (score 1):

NOT (`!`) has a few advantages:

1. it is more readable for most of people who will ever need to modify your code.
2. it is usually faster than `xor` (which gets two arguments while not takes only one)
3. it doesn't take less to type when you use short variable names:

   E.g. `a =! a` is shorter than `a ^= true`

Comment: I'd be curious to hear the justification for the speed claim. I agree with the general assertion, but not the claim that `xor` is slower.

Comment: That way of writing it would be slow, but XOR is usually a built-in operation at the chip level (single assembler language instruction) with a 1-cycle execution time — probably; I've not checked the cycle times on a CPU recently, but back in the days of Z80s, I'm fairly sure XOR between two registers was a single-cycle operation.

Comment: maybe reasonable in some cases, but it strongly depends on the processor; just to say, MMIX hasn't a bitwise `not` only op, and a compiler emitting MMIX code must use `xor` anyway - the same for MIPS (as far as I can remember), and I suspect it's so for many RISCs (maybe for [ARM too](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/I1010015.html) too).

Comment: @ShinTakezou: for ARM, see [XOR](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.kui0005a/a51_op_xor.htm).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think @webdev-dan concern is about the fact that, even supposing X is a register, on popular CISCs `not X` does not require an extra memory access, while `xor X, value` (or whatever) need to read value from memory... or anyway you need to preload it with another instruction… (but again, it depends on the specific cpu...)  — for ARM, didn't see it!

Comment: i think i found an answer - they take the same time - but XOR takes longer when one of operands is a `memory indirect operand` not a `register operand` - found it here: http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf

Comment: @JonathanLeffler but, in your link, it's not clear if it is talking about assembly syntax or actual instruction to perform a xor/not; it seems just the former.

Comment: @webdev-dan but as said, that stuff holds for x86 or alike cpus; in other cases, things may be different. It is just something to check case by case - and when it makes sense to optimize even this "bit".

Comment: @ShinTakezou i agree - it is always good idea to know your playground when you play optimalisation

Answer (score 1):

NOT because it is more readable and because it actually communicates what you intend to do. You want to negate a logical value, not perform an XOR operation.

Answer (score 1):

One benefit of the XOR method I'd like to point out is that you don't need to hard-code whether negation takes place.

```
bool isNegated;
//... later
return value ^ isNegated;
```

over

```
return isNegated ? !value : value;
```

I still use the latter for readability when I don't mind introducing a branch.